# Try/catch like: trigger URL on bash error

Tags: bash, error-handling, sh

I would have something like a big try/catch in a bash script (I would like to trigger an URL if something went wrong). Something like this:

1. Do task 1
2. Do task 2
3. ...
4. Do task 99
5. If any of this task has failed, stop the script (don't execute task >= 5 if task 4 failed) then trigger an URL (with curl or whatever)

I know `set -e` exists, but it just stops the script (it does the half job). Maybe there is something with `trap`, but I did not understand what I read about this. **Is there any simple example for this case?**

My question is obviously not about trigger the URL, but how to catch error then run an other part of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set -e` and you can trap the `ERR` pseudosignal and execute your `curl` statement if you script exits with an error. If all the tasks succeed, the `ERR` trap will not be triggered.

```
set -e
trap on_error ERR
on_error () {
    curl $some_url
}
task_1
task_2
# ...
task_last
```

Answer (score 3):

```
trap trap_exit EXIT
trap_exit() {
  CODE=$?
  if [ $CODE -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed! Return code: $CODE"
  fi
}
```

This will execute `trap_exit` whenever your script ends (the `EXIT` argument) and check if something broke (the `$?`part).

Comment: Ok so my code comes after this block and everything will be catched?

Comment: Yes, once `trap` is configured the `trap_exit` block will be called when the script finish -- aborted or not.